# Is there a way to stop UICollectionView from reusing cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, tablelayout, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to create a table in Swift 4, which contains both UITextFields and UILabels.

As I have many rows in the UICollectionView, scrolling is required.

However, when I scroll, the reuse function messes up the layout.

Is there another option than UICollectionView? In Android, where I have created a similar app, TableLayout renders all cells and doesn't cause any errors while scrolling.

**Desired layout**

[image]

**Layout after scrolling down and then up again**

[image]

I use this method for reuse:

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                                 cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
                                 UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! EUPCell

    cell.row = indexPath.section
    cell.column = indexPath.row
    //print("row: \(cell.row) column: \(cell.column)")
    CellCreation.make(self, indexPath, self.textfields, cell)

    return cell
}

static func make(_ view: EUPViewController,
                 _ indexPath: IndexPath,
                 _ textfields: TextFields,
                 _ cell: EUPCell) {

    let row = indexPath.section
    let column = indexPath.row

    if (row == 0 && column == 0) {
        CellCreation.makeLabel("Datum", cell)
    } else if (row == 0 && column == 1) {
        CellCreation.makeLabel("Skift", cell)
    } else if (row == 0 && column == 2) {
        CellCreation.makeLabel("EUP Operatör", cell)
    } else if (row == 0 && column == 3) {
        CellCreation.makeLabel("Kund", cell)
    } else if (row == 0 && column == 4) {
        CellCreation.makeLabel("Kontaktperson", cell)
    } else if (row == 0 && column == 5) {
        CellCreation.makeLabel("Artikel", cell)
    } else if (row == 0 && column == 6) {
        CellCreation.makeLabel("Plats", cell)
    } else if (row == 1 && (column >= 0 && column <= 6)) {
        CellCreation.makeInput(view, cell, textfields, false)
    } else if (row == 2 && column == 0) {
        CellCreation.makeLabel("Artikel nr", cell)
    } else if (row == 2 && column == 1) {
        CellCreation.makeLabel("Kolli nr", cell)
    } else if (row == 2 && column == 2) {
        CellCreation.makeLabel("FS nr", cell)
    } else if (row == 2 && column == 3) {
        CellCreation.makeLabel("Övrigt", cell)
    } else if (row == 2 && column == 4) {
        CellCreation.makeLabel("Antal i pall", cell)
    } else if (row == 2 && column == 5) {
        CellCreation.makeLabel("Antal OK", cell)
    } else if (row == 2 && column == 6) {
        CellCreation.makeLabel("Antal NOK", cell)
    } else if (row == 2 && column == 7) {
        CellCreation.makeLabel("Åtgärdade", cell)
    } else if (row == 2 && column == 8) {
        CellCreation.makeLabel("Utsorterade", cell)
    } else if ((row >= 3 && row <= 32) && (column >= 0 && column <= 8)) {
        columnCheck(view, column, cell, textfields)
    }
}

/**
 Uses a numeric keyboard for all UITextFields, except for those in
 the "Övrigt" column. This is equivalent to the fourth column
 of the table.
 */
static func columnCheck(_ view: EUPViewController,
                        _ column: Int,
                        _ cell: EUPCell,
                        _ textfields: TextFields) {

    if (column == 3) {
        CellCreation.makeInput(view, cell, textfields, false)
    } else {
        CellCreation.makeInput(view, cell, textfields, true)
    }
}

/**
 Creates an UILabel in the Cell. The font size
 is larger on an iPad.
 */
static func makeLabel(_ text: String, _ cell: EUPCell) {
    let label: UILabel
    let desiredFontSize: CGFloat

    label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height))

    if (UIDevice.modelName.contains("iPhone")) {
        desiredFontSize = 8.0
    } else {
        desiredFontSize = 13.0
    }

    let font = UIFont(name: desiredFont, size: desiredFontSize)
    label.font = font

    label.textAlignment = .center

    label.text = text
    cell.addSubview(label)
}

/**
 Creates an UITextField in the given Cell.
 */
static func makeInput(_ view: EUPViewController,
                      _ cell: EUPCell,
                      _ textfields: TextFields,
                      _ isNumeric: Bool) {

    let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height))

    let desiredFontSize: CGFloat

    if (UIDevice.modelName.contains("iPad")) {
        desiredFontSize = 14.0
    } else {
        desiredFontSize = 13.0
    }

    let font = UIFont(name: desiredFont, size: desiredFontSize)
    textField.font = font

    textField.delegate = view

    textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    textField.autocorrectionType = .no
    textField.textAlignment = .left

    textField.contentVerticalAlignment = .center

    if (isNumeric) {
        textField.keyboardType = .asciiCapableNumberPad
    } else {
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
    }

    textfields.add(textField)

    cell.addSubview(textField)
}
```

Comment: Yeah use `UIScrollView`. BTW what mess does `UICollectionView` created?

Comment: could you please post the widget tree setup and complete screen layout.

Comment: dahiya_boy: Thanks! I'll try that! The UICollectionView renders UITextFields on the rows where I only want to have UILabels.

Comment: Likely that you implement the reusing method wrong.

Comment: Don't try to avoid the Reuse Mecanism. It's an important memory/CPU optmization. Android use a similar system with its CycleView. You have to understand it and use it correctly instead.

Comment: Showing the code of `CellCreation.make(self, indexPath, self.textfields, cell)` could be a good start to help you to spot the mistakes.

Comment: Look for writing better code rather than looking for better UI 

Comment: Calling `addSubview()` each time in cellForRow is clearly not a good idea. Why don't you have a Custom UICollectionViewCell with already the UITextField, another one with only the UILabel, with all the settings needed, call them accordingly.

Comment: According to the code *the reuse function* **doesn't** *mess up the layout*, **you** do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- To avoid this mess you need to use two different types of cell.

  1. For Label as a header.
  2. For TextField as an input.
- Now you need to return 2 in `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView`

[image]

- Now set your cell size in `sizeForItem`. Make sure you added proper conditions for each cell.
- In `cellForItemAt`,

  ```
  if indexPath.section == 0  {
      if indexPath.row == 0  {
      // dequeue label Cell
      }
      // dequeue Textfield Cell            
  }
  else {
      if indexPath.row == 0  {
      // dequeue label Cell
      }
      // dequeue Textfield Cell    
  }
  ```

**Note:** To properly manage the data of textfield you need to do this -> [Swift UICollectionView Textfields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143119/swift-uicollectionview-textfields)